# Database calls shown in rails test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

My test suite consists of guard, rspec, spork and capybara. I am quite new to TDD but prior to learning it I would constantly be presented with the database queries being generated by rails in the server output (using thin). This was useful as I could instantly see when a query needed to be optimised further.

I was wondering whether this behaviour could be achieved with any of the gems for the above tools or if there was another gem that I could use in my tests to output similar information.

The main gems I use in my test suite are the following:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', "~> 2.35.1"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the test log for the generated database queries:

```
$ tail -f log/test.log
```

It displays all executed queries + a few insert and rollback statements used to setup your test database.

Comment: I suspect the queries are off by default. The problem is logging raw database queries is insecure (in production, obv), so modern Rails leaves all database query logging turned off.

Comment: @Philp I've just tested im my most recent app. It works for me in the test environment as stated above, I can't remember making any logger adjustments.

Comment: This does work, but how would I go about automating it with guard so that this is output as part of my tests. potentially optionally? I'll keep messing around and see what I can come up with

Comment: You're tailing the test log in a seperate console window usually. It's a different bash process than the test runs in rspec. There might be a way to pull in the log statements into the test result screen, but the result might be an overwhelming amount of information on the screen. Report back what you found out!

Comment: will do, it'll be a while until I really need to try and automate this but for the time being this does the trick nicely, thanks

Comment: Stupid, I was tailing `log/development.log` without luck

Answer (score 0):

This is a FAQ; try `ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG` in your environments/test.rb file.

Next, to learn Rails & TDD, do NOT use Capybara. Stick with RSpec. I *should* say to stick with normal test cases, but RSpec has eaten that space, so you will find lots of online support for it.

Capybara is for testing advanced & end-to-end things. You only need to TDD that your database contains such-and-so, and your generated web pages contain such-and-so, so stick with that.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, this doesn't work, it gives undefined method `level=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) there is a full stack trace if you need it.